# Area of connected region

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a binary image from which I want to measure the area of connected white  region manually, without using MATLAB functions. I have labeled the regions

```
I=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBaua.jpg')
[Label,Total]=bwlabel(I,8);
```

The Label is <669x585 double> variable that has all the connected white area labeled separately, starting from 1:Total. Here is the image:

[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use any built-in functions, you can easily loop through the labels and compute the number of pixels with a given label.

```
areas = arrayfun(@(x)sum(Label(:) == x), 1:max(Label(:)));
```

Alternately, you could use something like `accumarray` or `histcounts` to count them for you.

```
areas = accumarray(Label(:)+1, Label(:), [], @numel);
areas = histcounts(Label(:), 1:max(Label(:)));
```